# How do ansible host_vars work?

Tags: ansible

I [created a repo](https://github.com/balanced-ops/ansible-hostvars) to reproduce my scenario.

Essentially we are loading an inventory with our hosts, we can override values per-host via the inventory without issue but would like to try and utilize host_vars.

I'm not 100% clear on how host vars are matched to the host. I read the [ansible repo](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/search?q=host_vars&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) for examples but cannot seem to get it to work as documented so I'm looking for some scrutiny of our setup.

When I run the command `ansible-playbook -i ansible.inventory site.yml -clocal` in my example repo I expect the `host_vars/{{ ansible_hostname }}` file to be read and override anything set in the vars but that does not appear to be happening.

Can someone please point me at a working example so I can see where we are going wrong?

Answer (score 43):

Since the documentation is not very specific on this topic here is the order of precedence for vars in the current version of Ansible (the first item has the highest precedence):

1. Vars set on the command line *-e foo=set_on_cmd_line*
2. Vars set in the *vars_files:* block in the play
3. Vars set in the *vars:* block in the play
4. Vars set in *host_vars/*
5. Vars set in *group_vars/*
6. Role default vars *roles/.../defaults/main.yml*

See [Ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) for a more detailed list.

You should think of host_vars and group_vars more like defaults rather than overrides for defaults. If you have the same var set in you *vars_files:* block [like you do in your example](https://github.com/balanced-ops/ansible-hostvars/blob/master/site.yml) it will take precedence.

Comment: The paths that you have listed are *relative*, so what are they relative to? Where you run ansible-playbook? or something else?

Comment: paths are relative to where you run ansible-playbook

Comment: Note that, for inventory vars (e.g. `host_vars` and `group_vars`, you can also have those paths relative to the inventory file itself. E.g. if you have your inventory in `config/inventory`, then you could put host_vars files inside `config/host_vars/[hostname-here]`.

Comment: What is the best practice for defaults since apparently host_vars are overridden by vars_files. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'll address the title *"How do ansible host_vars work?"* as that's what people will search for.

Imagine you have a `hosts` file with one or more hosts which have many host variables:

```ini
[webservers]
production1 1.2.3.4 FOO=foo BAR=bar BAZ=3 QUX=4 HELLO=world SOMETHING=whatever CONFIG=42 SETTING=100 CONF=blah #...and many more host vars
production2 1.2.3.5 FOO=hello blah=10
```

You could replace it with this `hosts` file:

```ini
[webservers]
production1 1.2.3.4
production2 1.2.3.5 FOO=hello blah=10
```

And this `host_vars/production1.yml` file:

```yaml
---
FOO: foo
BAR: bar
BAZ: 3
QUX: 4
HELLO: world
SOMETHING: whatever
CONFIG: 42
SETTING: 100
CONF: blah
```

So just like `group_vars/` is for centralising variables for a group, `host_vars/` is for centralising variables for a host.

Just be aware of ansible's [rules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) for merging of variables.