# How to use host_vars in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I created a variable in `group_vars`

group_vars/all

```yaml
---
hostname: name1
```

I want to set name2 to the real host(10.20.30.40), so I created a file and set the hostname again there

host_vars/10.20.30.40

```yaml
---
hostname: name2
```

When I run the playbook, it returned name1 but not name2:

roles/os/tasks/main.yml

```yaml
- name: Print hostname
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ hostname }}"
```

Result:

```yaml
TASK [server : Print hostname] *************************************
ok: [web_server] => {
    "msg": "name1"
}
```

I want to set the variable in each host that I want to update, isn't it the right usage?

---

And, if I name the host file this way under the `host_vars` folder, does it work?

`web_server`

The inventory:

```
[web_server]
10.20.30.40
```

playbook:

```
---
- hosts: web_server
  become: true
  vars_files:
    - group_vars/all
  roles:
    - os
```

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76742348/9971404) for an explanation of `host_vars`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Q: *"**When I run the playbook, it returned name1 but not name2.**"*

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[web_server]
10.20.30.40
```

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all
---
hostname: name1
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/10.20.30.40 
---
hostname: name2
```

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
---
- hosts: web_server
  vars_files:
    - group_vars/all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: hostname
```

A: Don't include *group_vars/all* in a playbook.

The playbook's *group_vars/all* are included by the playbook automatically at precedence 5. See [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence). If you put *group_vars/all* into the *vars_files* (precedence 14) you override the *host_vars* (precedence 10).

---

**Example**. Given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[web_server]
10.20.30.40
10.20.30.41
```

the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
---
- hosts: web_server
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: hostname
```

gives as expected

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml 

PLAY [web_server] *********************************************************

TASK [debug] **************************************************************
ok: [10.20.30.40] => 
  hostname: name2
ok: [10.20.30.41] => 
  hostname: name1
```

The variable in `host_vars/10.20.30.40` override the variable in `group_vars/all`

Comment: `The playbook's group_vars/all are included by the playbook automatically at precedence 5 ...` Thank you for letting me know the precedence! That's the reason!